# Does Google Tag Manager code conflict with Google Analytics code implemented on the same site?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a CMS application that universally loads google analytics code. It looks like this & is dynamically loaded in the `<head>` tag on each of my clients sites.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-000000-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example.com']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Product','my-application',3]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'Sport','hockey',3]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 3, 'SiteID','121',3]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 4, 'State','MN',3]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 5, 'DMA','',3]);


(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

</script>
```

My client has implemented Google Tag Manager code just below the opening `<body>` tag (it looks like this)

```
<noscript>
<iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-O8EFGG"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>

<script>
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-O8EFGG');
</script>
```

I am under the impression that my application code will not conflict with the GTM code & vice verse. I want to confirm but haven't been able to dig up information on weather or not these can co-exist or if I need to migrate my UA code into my own GTM code.

Can someone confirm my assumptions are correct, that both the GTM code and the UA codes can run without conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code shouldn't conflict. However, the tracking results in Google Analytics will be extremely inaccurate unless you're careful not to double-track your page views or events or by sending the data collected by each method to two separate GA accounts.

Comment: I'm not tracking or wanting any data from the GTM, the client is also not wanting data from the UA code. If I am understanding you correctly as long as the clients GTM code isn't trying to track these I should be good to go?

_setAccount
_setDomainName
_trackPageview
_setCustomVar 1
_setCustomVar 2
_setCustomVar 3
_setCustomVar 4
_setCustomVar 5

Comment: I can't tell if what you are saying is correct based on the information you have provided. If both the standard tracking implementation and the GTM implementation send data to different accounts, or if you don't set up any trackers in GTM, then you are OK.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand this is abstract without actually seeing the account data, but in this instance the GTM code from the client and the UA code from the application are sending data to different accounts. Thanks for your help!